# Testing if two rankings are equivalent

Tags: correlation, ranking, wilcoxon-signed-rank, similarities, kendall-tau

I have some process A that assigns values `y_i` for `i=1:N` to instances `x_i`.  `N` may be very high, on the order of millions.  If I have some process B that assigns values `y_i'` to those same instances, then I would like to test whether the ranking produced by B is statistically similar to the one produced by A.

The Wilcoxon-signed rank test won't do here because it's the opposite of what I'm trying to show.  Wilcoxon's null hypothesis is that the two rankings are equal.  On the other hand, I am trying to reject a null hypothesis of significant *difference* in ranking.

I would prefer something that doesn't assume a normal distribution of values and that can be algebraically reasoned about, since what I am ultimately trying to show is that a certain algorithm can do a good job of approximating a true ranking.

Comment: Perhaps something like equivalence testing (TOST) is nearer to what you want.